# How do I turn off AirPlay on Apple Watch?

Tags: airplay, watchos

On the control center screen on my Apple Watch I accidentally turned on AirPlay. When I tap on it it gives me an option to cancel or select "Apple Watch...". I've tried both and neither option toggles AirPlay off. How do I turn off AirPlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned my watch off, let it reboot, problem solved.